# Do we need really need associativity in Wedderburn's little theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

Wedderburn's little theorem states that a finite division ring $R$ is necessarily commutative. At first sight this sounds plausible due to the following very informal reasoning:

the division property states that

for every fixed $a \in R$ the elements $\{ax \colon x \in R\}$ are all distinct

implying that the number of elements of $R$ must be big; and non-commutativity would imply that

for at least some $a, b \in R$ we have $ab$ distinct from $ba$

also implying that the number of elements of $R$ must be somewhat bigger than in the commutative case.

So if instead of being big the number of elements is small, something gotta give.

Of course the trouble with this heuristic is that it does not specify what we mean by "big" and "small" and at some point you realize that there exists  such a thing as finite groups, showing that the appropriate notion of "small" in this heuristic apparently is "smaller than 6" which is quite a long distance away from the "finite" in the theorem. In other words: the additive structure of $R$ apparently plays a highly non-trivial role in the proof and my heuristic is not very useful.

Nevertheless a question inspired by it :

In the same way as being noncommutative would force R to be bigger than it is, we would expect that being nonassociative would do the same. So the concrete question is: is there a variant of the theorem stating that every finite, possibly nonassociative divsion ring is necessarily commutative or, even better, associative (and hence commutative by Wedderburn's theorem)?

(At the risk of of sounding like an ungrateful spoiled brat: I know Zorn extended the theorem to alternative division rings but after having seen him generalize pretty much every result about associative algebras to the alternative case this hardly feels like a generalization anymore, or at least not taking full advantage of the finiteness.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there are nontrivial finite semifields (see here: http://scholar.lib.vt.edu/theses/available/etd-05182000-12080004/unrestricted/sfield.pdf Example 2.1) so in these formulation the fact does not hold. 
Actually, there is even a commutative example, see part on ``Dickson quadratic semifield''

Comment: Great this is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: It seems the link is broken now! Do you remember the name of the author so that we can find a new link?

Comment: Weirdly the link seems to work again. I list some info here in case it goes missing again: The title is 'On Nonassociative Division Rings and Projective Planes' and the author is Eric J. Landquist;it is a master's thesis from the Virginia Polytechnic Institute and State University